# Is $-\infty -i = -\infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Is $-\infty -i $ still equal to $ -\infty$?
In the text below, I kind of saw something like $icosh(\infty+iπ/2)-i=-\infty$?  As far as I know, $cosh(\infty+iπ/2)=i\infty$, thus $i(i\infty)=-\infty$. Now, is $-\infty-i$ equal to only -$\infty$ according to the text?

How is the substitution I putted in blue working? No matter what I do, I can not get the same result as in the text.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Often times in the context of complex analysis, we refer to **all** infinities as the same infinity, namely $\infty$.  Otherwise, we would have to deal with each of $\infty, i\infty, (1+i)\infty, (2+i)\infty, (1+2i)\infty, (3+i)\infty,\dots$ separately.  The only difference between these infinities is the direction of approach.  By looking at the complex plane with an added point for $\infty$ as [a sphere instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere), this simplifies matters considerably.  In such a context, $-\infty-i=\infty$

Comment: If you insist on dealing with the infinitely many different infinities all of the same cardinality (*e.g. $\infty, -\infty, i\infty, (1+i)\infty, (\pi+ei)\infty,\dots$ etc...*), then under most interpretations, yes $-\infty-i=-\infty$.  That being said, I much prefer working with the riemann sphere instead.  If you work with all of these different infinities, then even simple limits of sequences like $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(-e)^n$ will diverge rather than converge to $\infty$ like it would with the riemann sphere.

Comment: You should include Figure 6.11 because this is purely about contours.

Comment: @JMoravitz. Thank you for answering me. I am right now still confuded by the expression i cosh(∞+iπ/2)−i. What do you think this expression should be equal to?  cosh(∞+iπ/2) = i sinh(∞)=i∞=∞ ?  ∞ is then multiplied by i but it will still be ∞?   (1+i)∞ is certainly infinity in different direction than ∞+0i? But ∞+i will be infinity in same direction as ∞+0i since i is finite and negligible?

Comment: @mercio Yes, I just included it.